# How to move buttons up and down the page?

Tags: css

I have four buttons, each with an individual div class. The problem is that they don't seem to respond to obvious selectors.

I tried, for example:-

```
 @media (max-width:1920) and (min-width: 769) {.visit- 
 website {margin-top: 50px! 
 important;}}
```

Nothing.

Html:

```
 <div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>


 <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
 2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-service/"><div 
 class="email"><span><center>&#x1F4E7</center>. 
 </span></div></a><a href="tel:<br/><label>Phone: 
 </label> 07576335122"><div class="phone"><span>. 
 <center>&#128222</center></span></div></a>
 <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=:<br/>. 
 <label>Location:</label> Westminster, London, UK"><div 
class="location"><span><center>&#x1F4CD</center>. 
</span></div></a>

 <div class="visit-website"><Visit Website:</div>
 <br/><a  href="http://nicoscleaningservice.co.uk" 
  target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
```

Comment: I don't see any "buttons". Do you mean links? Your CSS selector doesn't apply to any of your links. It's only calling out the class of one of your `div`s. You also have a typo, an extra `<`: `<div class="visit-website"><Visit Website:</div>`. Finally, try formatting your HTML more sensibly (indentation, new lines). It will be a lot easier to read, understand, and update, and certainly more easy for others to follow.

Comment: It's complicated. My source html isn't accessible and posted html is only the result of source code. But thanks for your advice

Comment: Links then, whatever. Each link has a background color which looks like button. Want to target this. Icon for button can be adjusted later with line height

Comment: Example given only for one 'link'

Comment: Have 3 others....

Comment: Don't be casual about terminology (links v. buttons). Using proper terminology will help people to understand your question if you hope to get reasonable answers.

Comment: You aren't showing any CSS for your links. I don't know what you mean when you say they "don't respond to obvious selectors". The example selector you have doesn't associate with *any* link at all. It's associated with a `div` only.

Comment: Yes sir. So any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, so no, I don't have any ideas how to fix it. It's not clear what needs to be "fixed". You need to describe and/or show what you want to achieve. Something other than the vague: "doesn't respond to obvious selectors".

Comment: OK. So each link has a background color which looks like a button. I want to move this down.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "move this down".

Comment: Like move it down the page so it's lower down on the page

Comment: For example the link for. visit-website has a background color. It's shaped like a button. I'd like to move this further down the page

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s65qfyja/) showing what it currently looks like with the code you have shown. When saying you want something "lower down the page" you need to be specific. How far down the page? All the buttons further down the page? Bottom of the page? Middle of the page? After the "Visit" link? Still before the visit link? ... A picture of what you want would speak 1,000 words.

Comment: Sure. Have a look on desktop view https://www.adsler.co.uk you can see the buttons don't align horizontally https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-service/london/uk/westminster/business-advert/

Comment: You mean they don't align vertically, and that's all you need?

Comment: No horizontally.....

Comment: Need horizontal alignment

Comment: If the tops and bottoms don't align (which is what's happening on the page), that's called vertical alignment. Horizontal alignment would be if they were stacked one above the other and the left edge or right edge or centers weren't aligned.

Comment: I see. That's topsy-turvy :-) anyway, how to fix please?

Comment: Not topsy turvy. You have a horizontal *layout*, which requires vertical *alignment*. Anyway, what I would recommend, especially since the CSS you do show implies you might be interested in proper behavior for mobile as well as desktop, is look into using the HTML5 grid technology. You can Google it and there are numerous helpful tutorials. For example: [W3 school grid technology tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).